# Using wait statements with signals

Tags: signals, wait, thread-sleep, systemc

Is it possible to use a wait statement with an input signal in a thread, i.e.

```
void Thread::myThread(){
   while(1){
      wait(mySignal);
      if(mySignal == 1){
         //do stuff
      }
   }
}
```

where `mySignal` is `sc_in<int> mySignal;`

I tried to run a similar variation, but i get the following error when i try to step over the wait statement. [image]

From what I've been able to read about `waits`, it seems they take time, events, and some other combinations, but not directly a signal.

Assuming i cannot use the signal directly inside the wait, could i achieve the same result by making the thread sensitive in the constructor, i.e.

```
SC_MODULE(myModule){
   sc_in<bool> mySignal;

   void myThread();

   SC_CTOR(myModule){
      SC_THREAD(myThread)
      sensitive << mySignal;
   }
}

void myModule::myThread(){
   while(1){
       wait(); //Wait for mySignal
        if(mySignal == 1){
           //do stuff
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are slight inconsistencies in your code.
Try changing your code to this:

```
SC_MODULE(myModule){
  sc_in<bool> mySignal;
  void myThread();
  SC_CTOR(myModule){
    SC_THREAD(myThread); //<< SC_THREAD is a macro.
    sensitive << mySignal;
  }
}

void myModule::myThread(){ //<< Did you mean this instead of Thread class
  while(1){
    wait(); //Wait for mySignal
    if(mySignal == 1){
      //do stuff
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Yes, typo mistake on my part with the thread code. Assuming the correct version, will SC_THREAD react to any changes on mySignal? And is wait(mySignal); invalid?

Comment: Yes wait(mySignal) is invalid. **Note:** If you don't provide any sensitivity at the time of construction(i.e. removing the sensitive statement from constructor), you can use the **wait(mySignal.default_event())** for waiting for the mySignal to change in this scenario your thread has now dynamic sensitivity.

Comment: I think wrapping the `wait()` with a `while(mySignal != 1) wait();` is safer to ensure waking up by the right signal status.

Comment: @AmeyaVS using mySignal.default_event() throws the warning: channel doesn't have a default event